# Show button animation with a transparent BckgroundColor

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I need to create a `button` by placing the image as a separate control because I have a `nuget` extension that allows me to change its color. But I would like to create the classic animation of the `button` when pressing on it, but I would like the `button` not to have a background color, is that possible?

```
<abstractions:TintedImage 
            x:Name="profile"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=Constant,
            Constant=20}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=Constant,
            Constant=300}"
            WidthRequest="20"
            Source="User"
            TintColor="{x:DynamicResource TextColor}"/>
        
        <Button
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=Constant,
            Constant=10}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=Constant,
            Constant=295}"
            HeightRequest="50"
            WidthRequest="50"
            Clicked="ButtonSettings_Clicked"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```

[Video demo](https://1drv.ms/v/s!ApEbJKXRW_xfjBYtxDI2tCVcyXp4?e=tWMbMY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called **RippleEffect** on Android, you can use `TouchEffect` from [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit)

```
       <Button xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=Constant,
            Constant=10}"
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=Constant,
            Constant=295}"
            HeightRequest="50"
            WidthRequest="50"
            Clicked="ButtonSettings_Clicked"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
```

You can also specify:

- The effect color thru: `NativeAnimationColor`
- The effect radius thru: `NativeAnimationRadius`
- The effect shadow radius thru: `NativeAnimationShadowRadius`

and a lot more for that effect, a non-exhausted sample could be found in the official repo [TouchEffectPage.xaml](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Effects/TouchEffectPage.xaml)

Comment: does it provide the same effect on iOs too?

Comment: I don't think so, it will probably provide a different effect that is native to iOS, but you can use `PressedOpacity` or `PressedBackgroundColor` as an alternative and it will work on both Android and iOS the same

Comment: If I insert the effect on a layout (Grid, etc.) it replicates the effect very well. On the other hand, on a button it is different. How can I recreate the fade effect? From the official repo there is no guide to the various properties. I can't figure out what values I should put in some properties

Comment: unfortunately the docs is not yet ready :/, what do you mean it different? is it the same behavior with Visual = Default and Material? you can try it with a Label or a Frame + GestureReconizer.Tapped event

Comment: By inserting the control into the button, although I have entered the PressedBackGroundColor and then PressedOpacity at 0.3, when I press and then release, the button for a moment becomes the color I entered but with an opacity of 1, is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: Not sure about this, are you using NativeAnimation at the same time ?

Comment: [video example](https://1drv.ms/v/s!ApEbJKXRW_xfjBeCm5EOxzsKEXZB?e=9pxTum)